# Format a string with html elements in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to create a component to display some generic product info. The string is formatted by a CRM so it has HTML elements in it `"<BR>, <b> </b>` etc.
eg:

```
"<BR>Łosoś to<b> szlachetna ryba,</b> można z niej przyrządzać przepyszne dania główne, genialne przystawki, a także niezwykle smaczne pasztety i farsze. Doskonale nadaje się do<b> pieczenia, smażenia, duszenia i grillowania. <BR><BR>Trym D:</b> Usunięty kręgosłup, ości brzuszne, tylne płetwy, kość obojczyka, tłuszcz na płetwie brzusznej usunięty częściowo, usunięte ości, ścięty ogon, usunięta otrzewna.<BR>"
```

I want to format the string so it renders properly in react native.

I tried using ramda's replace and it worked for adding new lines `/n` however I do not think this will work for making the text bold. 
is there some library that will format strings with html elements into a react native friendly format?

Comment: try Html.fromHtml(yourHTMLString)

Comment: your can use `WebView` component for rendering HTML  in React-Native.